# Deploying A Static Webpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, netlify

I have created my resume/cv with HTML5 and CSS3. I now need to deploy it on the web. The 3 options I have are Heroku, Netlify and AWS. From what I have read, they seem to work the same. Which one is the most suitable platform for CV/Resume deployment?

Comment: There is  no "correct" answer, answers will just be opinions.  Here's mine: If you already use one of them or knowledge of it is listed in your CV then using that platform would help demonstrate your knowledge.  I use AWS for work, so I'd use S3 for static or EC2 for dynamic.

Comment: I am learning all the platforms at the same time.

Comment: Then you could place your CV on all 3 if all 3 have free tiers.  If you own a domain you could use different subdomains for each one, for example  s3.MYDOMAIN.com netify.MYDOMAIN.com .  You might need to use the their own domains if you want HTTPS on the free tiers but LetsEncrypt might work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS S3 static web hosting while staying in the free tier. Configuration should only take 5-15 minutes if you fallow the instructions below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html